# Convert string to hexadecimal value [C++]

Tags: string, char, hex

I am working on a program that concatenates several strings, then adds all of their values in hex.
When I try to convert a string to an int (for example string1), it does not seem to work right.
When I run the code and print string1 to the serial monitor, I get "0" instead of "11" like I would expect.

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // these are hexadecimal values
  String string0 = "06";
  String string1 = "000B";
  String string2 = "00FE";
  
  // add the individual hex values of string0, string1, string2
  int checkSum0 = string0.toInt(); // this will be in decimal form, right?
  int checkSum1 = string1.toInt(); // this too?
  int checkSum2 = string2.toInt(); // this too?
  int checkSumTotal = checkSum0 + checkSum1 + checkSum2;
  // convert checkSumTotal to hexadecimal
  Serial.println(checkSum1); // prints 0 when I run the code

}
```

Comment: This uses the Arduino String class, not the C++ standard library string

Comment: [Arduino Reference](https://cdn.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/)
"If the String contains non-integer numbers, the function will stop performing the conversion. ". So it cannot convert 'B'.

Comment: If you have a char array, assuming the value won't overflow, you can do something like `strtoul(char_array, NULL, 16)`. And since you have `String`, maybe you can read about [toCharArray](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/). Depending on what you want, a buffer can be declared like `char buffer[5] {0,0,0,0,0};`, or you may read about dynamic allocation if the size is unknown until runtime

Answer (score 0):

The toInt() function can only convert the string into a decimal integer and it does not work for Hexadecimal numbers. You can use a library function called strtol() which can be used to convert a string into a integer according to a given base from 2 to 36. I have modified your code using strtol() for Hexadecimal number as follows:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // these are hexadecimal values
  String string0 = "06";
  String string1 = "000B";
  String string2 = "00FE";

  // add the individual hex values of string0, string1, string2
  int checkSum0 = strtol(string0.c_str(), NULL, 16);  //modified code
  int checkSum1 = strtol(string1.c_str(), NULL, 16);  //modified code
  int checkSum2 = strtol(string2.c_str(), NULL, 16);  //modified code
  int checkSumTotal = checkSum0 + checkSum1 + checkSum2;

  // convert checkSumTotal to hexadecimal
  Serial.println(checkSum1);
 }
```

Hope it helps! :D